# Flutter - Implement an async function from showBottomSheet

Tags: flutter

I have a function that call `showModalBottomSheet` which I need to remove the barrier.

```
  Future<..> popup() async => await showModalBottomSheet<..>(
    ...
      builder : (BuildContext context){
        ...
        Navigator.of(context).pop(..);
        ...
      }
    );
```

I have two options. Since I don't want to use different `Scaffold`, that leaves me to use `showBottomSheet` instead. But I also want to keep my function as `async` because I need the `BottomSheet` to return a value on it's dismiss. `showBottomSheet` returns `PersistentBottomSheetController` not a `Future`. I have no idea how to implement a `Future` returning function from it, the way I did with `showModalBottomSheet`.

```
 Future<..> popup() async{
   ???
   Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet(..)<..>(
     (BuildContext context){
       ...
       Navigator.of(context).pop(..);
       ...
     }
   );
   ???
 }
```

Greatly appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return Future from `showModalBottomSheet` instead
you can use `isClosed` to check if bottom sheet closed and this getter return future.

you can use it like:

```
Future<bool> popup(BuildContext context) async{
    PersistentBottomSheetController myModal = showBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return const Text("Modal");
      },
    );
    Future<bool> isClosed = await myModal.closed;
    return isClosed;
  }
```

Comment: i still have to set the value indirectly than via navigator.of(context).pop(). but an answer is an answer. thank you much